# PhpMyAdmin 4.5.x: Column Comments no longer showing when printing table structure

Tags: phpmyadmin

It seems that after upgrading from PhpMyAdmin 4.4.15 to 4.5.x, when getting a print view of a table's structure, the column comments are no longer included in the print view. Is there a way to get them back? I've searched the config options and haven't had any luck.

The release notes for 4.5 indicate "Improved Print View" -- does anyone know the rationale for removing column comments from the print view?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an oversight from the transition to the new print system. I've opened a ticket about it at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11730 and you can follow discussion/progress there.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Isaac. Looks like it has been taken care of.